# Confusion when comparing StartDate and EndDate in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, date

I am a bit confused when comparing StartDate and EndDate in my asp.net app.

```
EndDate:    10/1/2011
StartDate:  9/30/2011
```

The if statement below returns true, based on the date values above.

If strEndDate < strStartDate Then

I would think the If statement shoudl return false. The concept is supposed to be that if EndDate is earlier than StartDate, display an error message.

Comment: What .Net data types are these values stored in ?

Comment: "str" and other Hungarian notation (int, bln, etc) is considered bad form these days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using [`DateTime.Compare`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare.aspx#Y798).

```
Dim date1 As Date = DateTime.Parse(strStartDate)
Dim date2 As Date = DateTime.Parse(strEndDate)
Dim result As Integer = DateTime.Compare(date1, date2)
Dim relationship As String

If result < 0 Then
   relationship = "is earlier than"
ElseIf result = 0 Then
   relationship = "is the same time as"         
Else
   relationship = "is later than"
End If

Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", date1, relationship, date2)
' The example displays the following output:
'    8/1/2009 12:00:00 AM is earlier than 8/1/2009 12:00:00 PM
```

Comment: This answer is misleading. Comparing dates with "greater than" and "smaller than" signs is perfectly legitimate, the OP's problem is that he was comparing strings. Using DateTime.Compare is not necessary, and actually makes code less clear IMO.

Comment: I guess you missed this part:  DateTime.Parse(strStartDate), two down-votes thus far. woot! Also, the OP never stated they are strings, it's inferred by the str.

Comment: shott: nope, didn't miss it, you stated "you SHOULD be using DateTime.Compare", that's the confusing part.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that since your variables are called `strEndDate` and `strStartDate` that they're strings, not `DateTime`s.  Since they're strings, and since '1' < '9' (the first characters in the strings), `strEndDate` is indeed "less than" `strStartDate`.

Convert the values to `DateTime` before comparing:

```
If DateTime.Parse(strEndDate) < DateTime.Parse(strStartDate) Then
    '...
End If
```

Answer (score 3):

If those are DateTime variables, that code should evaluate to true. If not, you should convert them to DateTime.

```
DateTime start = DateTime.Parse(strStartDate);
DateTime close = DateTime.Parse(strEndDate);

if (close > start)
    //do something
```

You can also compare them like this:

```
if ((close - start).TotalDays > 0)
    //do something
```

As Rick Schott pointed out, you can also use `DateTime.Compare`

Answer (score 1):

Don't compare them as strings, compare them as dates.